# why is this angular dependency not being picked up?

Tags: html, angularjs, javascript

I have an angular app, and I am separating out my logic into individual files.  The app.js, services.js and controllers.js just stub out the modules.  I am providing implementation in individual files.

I am having trouble getting one of my services (which depends on another service) to pick up my dependencies.  I keep getting an error from $injector saying Unknown Provider.

So:  in services.js:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']);
```

controllers.js:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.services', 'myApp.controllers']);
```

settingsService.js:

```
angular.module('myApp.services').factory('SettingsService', function() { /* implementation here */ });
```

customerService.js:

```
angular.module('myApp.services').factory('CustomerService', ['$resource', 'SettingsService', function($resource, settings) {  /* implementation here */ }]);
```

No matter what order I put $resource and SettingsService in, or even if I only use one of them, I get the aforementioned UnknownProvider error.  If I remove both of them and just put a test function in CustomerService - it works just fine.  For the sake of completeness, here is how I am referencing CustomerService elsewhere:

customerController.js:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
.controller('CustomerController', ['$scope', 'CustomerService', function($scope, $customerService) {  /* I can call methods on $customerService just fine here... */
```

All the files are being included on my index.html, and here is the relevant excerpt:

```
<script src="lib/js/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>

<!-- MASTER scripts -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

<!-- App Services -->
<script src="js/services/settingsService.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/menuService.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/customerService.js"></script>

<!-- App Controllers -->
<script src="js/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/customerController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/todosController.js"></script>
```

So yeah.  Help?  Every similar answer I have seen and the angular docs all seem to say what I'm doing should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to start from scratch.  Created a new project entirely, and started pasting in code from files one by one.  Now it works.

So the answer all along was...

...sunspots?
...solar flares?
...dust mites?
...ghost in the machine?

I guess it's good to know I'm not going nuts.  It all looked fine to me from the get-go.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
```

Is missing your services as dependancy. Use

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.services']);
```

If you want to use the services in your controllers module.

Comment: No dice, sir.  The problem is in CustomerService trying to depend on ngResource.  If I remove all the dependencies from customerService.js, it works, and I can use it in my controller - no reference to myApp.services required.  it's like it won't pick any ANY dependencies.  Even changing it to just $resource results in the same error, and I am clearly including ngResource when I create the module.

Comment: Did you include [angular-resource.js](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular-resource.min.js) file?

Comment: Yessir.  Updated original post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Your injected name should match the defined name in the factory:

angular.module('myApp.services').factory('CustomerService', ['$resource', 'SettingsService', function($resource, **SettingsService**){  /* implementation here */ }]);

angular.module('myApp.controllers')
.controller('CustomerController', ['$scope', 'CustomerService', function($scope, **CustomerService**) {  /* I can call methods on $customerService just fine here... */

Comment: Again - this is not the problem.  If I remove SettingsService altogether, I still get the same error for $resource.  Using ngResource also fails.

Comment: @MonkRocker did you include 'angular.js' in your index.html ?

Comment: Yes.  Pretty sure it would be failing long about the first call to angular.module if that were the case.

Comment: @MonkRocker post a jsffidle or plunkr, could be that the Services have been implemented wrongly. You also have to inject 'ngResource' into the services module if you are using $resource. `angular.module('myApp.services',['ngResource'])`

Comment: That is literally the first line of code I posted.  I realize you're trying to help, but could you actually READ the question first?